# Using same product identifier across iOS and tvOS app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit, tvos

We have an auto-renewable subscription that we want to share across our iOS(iphone/ipad) and tvOS apps. I suppose I have two questions:

1. Can we use the same product identifier across both iOS and tvOS?
2. If the answer to 1 is yes, how does a user who purchased a subscription on one platform receive it on another platform? We have no unique identifier for the user across the two platforms other than that they are using the same iTunes account. Does the user have to manually restore the purchase?

Answer (score 0):

1. https://developer.apple.com/support/universal-purchase/ states that you can share in app purchases between ios and tvos

> To distribute your iOS app and tvOS app together with a universal purchase, both apps need to use the same app record in iTunes Connect. You can create a new app for both iOS and tvOS using the same app record or add a platform to your existing app record. The iOS app and tvOS app share the same bundle ID but must have their own version in the app record and must be uploaded separately.

2. You will need to have the user restore their in-app purchases on the other device.

> To make an In-App Purchase available on both platforms, you’ll need to implement the same In-App Purchase in both versions of your app. After you’ve enabled your app for universal purchase in My Apps on iTunes Connect, customers can restore your In-App Purchases on both platforms.

e.g. The user purchase a subscription on their iPhone and they can consume the content immediately. They then open the app on their Apple TV, but the content is not available until they restore their purchases. Once restored their content is available.